# Running several methods in a WaitAll

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have several methods which are database access tools.

```
await Task.WaitAll() {
  one();
  two();
  three();
 }
```

None of the methods are async, So how do I wrap them in a task so that I can await them and have them all run in their own Task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put each method in a `Task.Run`:

```
List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>()
{
   Task.Run(new Action(one)),
   Task.Run(new Action(two)),
   Task.Run(new Action(three)),
};
await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
```

Note that the awaitable version of this method is actually `WhenAll` not `WaitAll` (which blocks synchronously).

Of course, this is a lot simpler if the methods already return `Task` objects.